# Reutilizar código hecho con la librería append( )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

En el fichero jsp aplico en varias partes del código, la librería "append( )" de jQuery. El inconveniente que veo es que hay código repetido hasta en tres ocasiones, además suelen ocupar más de cinco líneas de código por cada "append( )". No os pasaré el código completo, sino un fragmento de código.

**Código HTML.**

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="conexion-chat">
    <button id="btn-conexion-chat" onclick="initWebSocket();">Iniciar chat</button>
</div>

<div id="display-chat" class="container" style="display: none;">
    <h3 class=" text-center">Messaging</h3>
    <div class="messaging">
        <div class="inbox_msg">
            <div class="inbox_people">
                <div class="headind_srch">
                    <div class="recent_heading"><h4>Visitantes</h4></div>
                </div>
                <div class="inbox_chat"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="mesgs">
                <div class="headind_srch">
                    <div class="recent_heading"><h4></h4></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mesgs-display">
                    <div class="msg_history">
                        <div class="msg-incoming-outgoing"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="type_msg">
                        <div class="input_msg_write">
                            <input id="sendField" type="text" class="write_msg" placeholder="Type a message" />
                            <button id="sendButton" onclick="send_message();" class="msg_send_btn" type="button">
                                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <p class="text-center top_spac"> Design by <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/sunil-rajput-nattho-singh/">Sunil Rajput</a></p>     
    </div>
</div>
```

**Código javascript/jQuery.**
En la función "processMessage", se aplican todos los "append()" del fichero jsp. Como se puede apreciar hay código que se añaden a dicha librería que se repiten.

```
function processMessage(message){

    if(message == '${disconnected}'){
        $('.msg-incoming-outgoing').append(
            '<div class="incoming_msg">' +
                '<div class="incoming_msg_img">' +
                    '<img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="image_chat">' + 
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="received_msg">' +
                    '<div class="received_withd_msg">' +
                        '<p>El patrocinador no se encuentra conectado.</p>' +
                       '</div>' +
                  '</div>' +
               '</div>'
        );
        
    }else {
        
        var json_message = JSON.parse(message);
        var visitorSelected = $('.active_chat').find('h5').data('id');
                
        if(json_message.hasOwnProperty('message') && message.length > 0){
            var message = json_message.message;
            
            //Visitante
            if('${currentUserRol}' != '${rolPreferences}'){
                $(".msg-incoming-outgoing").children().remove();
                
                for(var i=0; i<message.length; i++){
                    
                    if(message[i].rol != '${rolPreferences}'){
                        $('.msg-incoming-outgoing').append(
                            '<div class="outgoing_msg">' +
                                '<div class="sent_msg">' +
                                    '<p>' + message[i].message + '</p>' +
                                    '<span class="time_date">' + message[i].hour + ' | ' + message[i].date + '</span>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>'
                        );  
                        
                    }else{
                        $('.msg-incoming-outgoing').append(
                            '<div class="incoming_msg">' +
                                '<div class="incoming_msg_img">' +
                                    '<img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="image_chat">' + 
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div class="received_msg">' +
                                    '<div class="received_withd_msg">' +
                                        '<p>' + message[i].message + '</p>' +
                                        '<span class="time_date">' + message[i].hour + ' | ' + message[i].date + '</span>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>'
                        );
                        
                    }
                }
                    
            }else{ 
                //Patrocinador
                if(message[message.length-1].id == visitorSelected || message[message.length-1].idTo == visitorSelected){
                    $(".msg-incoming-outgoing").children().remove();
                    
                    for(var i=0; i<message.length; i++){
                        
                        if(message[i].rol != '${rolPreferences}'){
                            $('.msg-incoming-outgoing').append(
                                '<div class="incoming_msg">' +
                                    '<div class="incoming_msg_img">' +
                                        '<img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="image_chat">' + 
                                    '</div>' +
                                    '<div class="received_msg">' +
                                        '<div class="received_withd_msg">' +
                                            '<p>' + message[i].message + '</p>' +
                                            '<span class="time_date">' + message[i].hour + ' | ' + message[i].date + '</span>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>'
                            );
                            
                        }else{
                            $('.msg-incoming-outgoing').append(
                                '<div class="outgoing_msg">' +
                                    '<div class="sent_msg">' +
                                        '<p>' + message[i].message + '</p>' +
                                        '<span class="time_date">' + message[i].hour + ' | ' + message[i].date + '</span>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>'
                            );      
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }else{
                    var idMessage = message[message.length-1].id;
                    $('h5[data-id=' + idMessage + ']').parent().parent().parent().addClass('unread');
                }   
            }
        }
        
        if(json_message.hasOwnProperty('visitors') && json_message.visitors.length > 0){
            var visitors = json_message.visitors;
            var visitorSelected = $('.active_chat').find('h5').data('id');
            var state;
            
            $(".chat_list").remove();
            
            for (var i = 0; i < visitors.length; i++) {
                state = (visitors[i].idSession == visitorSelected)? "active_chat": "";
                
                $('.inbox_chat').append(
                    '<div class="chat_list ' + state + '">' +
                        '<div class="chat_people">' +
                            '<div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="image_chat"> </div>' +
                            '<div class="chat_ib">' +
                                '<h5 data-id=' + visitors[i].idSession + '>' + visitors[i].visitorOnline + '</h5>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Quiero saber si es posible reutilizar lo que contiene cada "append( )" para poder llamarlo desde diferentes partes del código.

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿En qué momento se repiten los mensajes? El problema puede ser que al obtener los datos no estés filtrando correctamente la consulta. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código de la petición AJAX y el de la consulta para leer los mensajes.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta. He puesto la función "processMessage( )" completa, donde se aplican todos los append( ). Podrás comprobar que el código html que se añade a dicha librería se repite en distintas partes de dicha función. Por otro lado, no dispongo de una función AJAX, ya que se está trabajando con websocket. A su vez, si es necesario que lo redacte mejor, me lo dices y haré los cambios en la pregunta.

Comment: Puedes usar la interpolación y te sugeriría usar acentos graves... tienes tu "template" por así decirlo, entonces sería crear un método que agregue el contenido al div.

Comment: Respecto a los acentos graves te refieres, a los acentos inclinados, ¿cierto?. Por otro lado, un ejemplo de interpolación de cadenas sería ${nombre}, ¿no?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto a las plantillas, puedes usar la etiqueta [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template), que no se muestra en el navegador y puedes usar cuantas veces quieras para actualizar contenido.

```js
const message = [
    {rol: 0, message: 'Enviado 1', hour: '01:10', date: '2021-05-14' },
    {rol: '${rolPreferences}', message: 'Recibido 1', hour: '01:11', date: '2021-05-14' },
    {rol: 0, message: 'Enviado 2', hour: '01:12', date: '2021-05-14' },
    {rol: '${rolPreferences}', message: 'Recibido 2', hour: '01:15', date: '2021-05-14' }
];

message.forEach(msg => {
    // Obtener plantilla de acuerdo al rol
    let html = (msg.rol != '${rolPreferences}')
        ? $('#template-out').html()
        : $('#template-in').html();
    // Remplazar variables en la plantilla
    html = html.replace('{{message}}', msg.message)
        .replace('{{hour}}', msg.hour)
        .replace('{{date}}', msg.date);
    // Actualizar contenedor
    $('.msg-incoming-outgoing').append(html);
});
```

```css
.outgoing_msg { text-align: right; }
img { max-width: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template id="template-out">
    <div class="outgoing_msg">
        <div class="sent_msg">
            <p>{{message}}</p>
            <span class="time_date">{{hour}} | {{date}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template id="template-in">
    <div class="incoming_msg">
        <div class="incoming_msg_img">
            <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="Image chat">
        </div>
        <div class="received_msg">
            <div class="received_withd_msg">
                <p>{{message}}</p>
                <span class="time_date">{{hour}} | {{date}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<div class="msg-incoming-outgoing"></div>
```

En algunos casos puede servirte esta opción, aunque en otros, quizá las [plantillas de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) de Javascript puedan ser mejores. Por ahora, teniendo ambas plantillas con las mismas variables, creo que con la etiqueta `<template>` vas bien.

En cuanto a la lógica de tu script veo varios problemas:

**El más importante:** Estás eliminando todo el contenido del chat con `$(".msg-incoming-outgoing").children().remove();`, por lo que supongo que en cada petición vuelves a cargar todos los mensajes; en una conversación corta no habrá problema, pero el tiempo de respuesta se va a ir incrementando conforme se agreguen más mensajes.

Aquí lo adecuado sería que guardes en una variable la fecha y hora (o ID) del último mensaje recibido, de forma que puedas enviarlo como parámetro en la petición AJAX y obtengas solo los nuevos mensajes.

Por ejemplo, si los mensajes tienen ID autoincrementable:

```
// Defines una variable global
let lastMessage = 0;

// Cuando ejecutes la petición para obtener mensajes
function leeMensajes() {
    let data = {
        usuario1: 'nombre o id del usuario 1',
        usuario2: 'nombre o id del usuario 2',
        last: lastMessage
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ruta/archivo.extension',
        method: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: processMessage
    });
}
```

En el servidor vas a generar la consulta para obtener los mensajes entre estos dos usuarios a partir del último recibido. Supongamos que tu base de datos es MySQL, especifica los campos adecuados y remplaza `usuario1`, `usuario2` y `last` por las variables que hayas obenido

```
SELECT * from messages
WHERE (`usuario` = usuario1 OR `usuario` = usuario2) AND `id` > last
ORDER BY `date`, `hour`
```

En la función donde muestras los mensajes actualizar la variable de acuerdo al último recibido:

```
function processMessage(message) {
    message.forEach(msg => {
        // Primero muestras el contenido con las plantillas
        // Al final, actualizas la variable
        lastMessage = msg.id
    });
}
```